# A question on Fubini's Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We have been asked to investigate whether $\int_{[0,1]^2} f \, d\lambda^2$ exists and if so whether it is equal to $\int_0^1 (\int_0^1f(x,y) \, d\lambda(x)) \, d\lambda(y)$ and $\int_0^1 (\int_0^1 f(x,y) \, d\lambda(y)) \, d\lambda(x)$ for $f(x,y) = (x^2 - y^2)(x^2 + y^2)^{-2}$.

So far we have worked out that since $f$ is continuous on the unit square it is $\lambda_2$ lebesgue measurable. So for $f$ to satisfy Fubini's theorem we just need to show $\int_{[0,1]^2}|f| \, d\lambda^2$ is intergrable. We were wondering if it is enough to show that the Riemann integral $\int_0^1 (\int_0^1 f(x,y) \, dx) \, dy$ is integrable, and if this means the Lebesgue integral is equal to the Riemann integral?

Comment: Note that the function is symmetric, but you have a *minus* on the numerator...

Answer (score 1):

If you compute the integrals $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)\, dx\, dy$ and $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)\, dy\, dx$ directly, you would find that they are not equal (the latter integral is $\pi/4$ and the former is $-\pi/4$). Furthermore, the integral $\int_{[0,1]^2} |f|\, d\lambda_2$ does not exist. For if it did, then since $|f|$ is nonnegative, Fubini's theorem would imply $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\, dy\, dx < +\infty$. However,

\begin{align*}\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\, dy\, dx &= \int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}\, dy\, dx + \int_0^1 \int_x^1 \frac{y^2 - x^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}\, dy\, dx\\ 
&= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)\bigg|_{y = 0}^{y = x} + \int_0^1 \left(-\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)\bigg|_{y = x}^{y = 1}\, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2x}\, dx + \int_0^1 \left(\frac1{2x} - \frac1{1 + x^2}\right)\, dx\end{align*}

and the last two integrals diverge to $+\infty$.

Comment: I'm not sure how it follows from Fubini that if the integral $|f|$ exists, it is finite, can you elaborate?

Comment: @AlexBowring are you asking why $\int_{[0,1]^2} |f|$ is finite if it exists? I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: yes that is what i am asking

Comment: That has nothing to do with Fubini's theorem. It has to do with the definition of the integral. If you use the extended real number system, you can say e.g. that $\int_{[0,1]^2} |f| = \infty$. But in the post, existence refers to existence of the integral as a real number.

Comment: If you were thinking from the start that $\int_{[0,1]^2} |f|$ is the same as $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |f|\, dy\, dx$, then that might explain the confusion. The integral $\int_{[0,1]^2} |f|$ is the Lebesgue integral of $|f|$ over the square $[0,1]^2$ with respect to $\lambda^2$, and $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |f|\, dy\, dx$ is an iterated integral.

Comment: I don't think that Fubini would imply that the integral is well defined. However the integral is not well defined, therefore you cannot apply Fubini. (Furthermore it is true that if you evaluate the two integrals you get two numbers with opposite sign.)

Comment: Thank you, I think i understand now. One more question i'm not sure about is why you are able to take the riemann integrals? Clearly the function is not bounded on the unit square